# JS for plain html table to Bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, python, html

I made this Python script that parses a JSON file and creates a table with the data and outputs a html file. I'm making a html webapp using Bootstrap so the data would fit all nice in the table created using bootstrap. Now, I'm trying to take that output file (.html) and make a script with JS that opens the outputted file, reads it and puts that data in the bootstrap table. I've never really worked with JS before and I can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: you can try the jquery framework that would take the desired tag and add to it some html

Comment: `document.querySelector('table').classList.add('table')`

Comment: If the Python script outputs an HTML file, why can't you just view it or customize the script to include Bootstrap? It would help if you included the Python script you used, as well as (some of) the raw JSON data.

Comment: @ItaiSteinherz thats what I thought I'd try to do at first but have no idea how to add bootstrap to python

Comment: You don't need to add Bootstrap to the Python script, but to add it to the HTML file you're creating in the Python script. Check out [Bootstrap's Getting Started guide](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/) for more info on this.